# Problems Launching Word From VBA Excel Editor

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, operating-system, com

So I had VBA code that I was using for a few months from late 2022 to early 2023 to write information from an excel spreadsheet into word. I had no problems running it at that point, but haven't touched it since about February.

Yesterday, I was about to begin the process of writing a similar program for the updated version of the spreadsheet we use, but went into the old one just to test the old code and make sure it still worked. However, upon trying to run it, I was met with the following error:

```
Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.
```

The code causing the issue:
either

```
Dim Word As Word.Application
Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

or

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

neither works, and causes this error. Just to test, I also tried using `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` in Word's VBA editor, and was met with the same error.

I have yet to find the solution to this issue.

So far, I've repaired Office 365, checked to make sure that the ProgID's are registered correctly (they are), and checked the .dll files (Microsoft article on the error said to do this. My .dll file versions/creation dates don't seem to line up, but I'm not really knowledgeable about the functionality of these, so I haven't done anything with them as of yet. I checked these after I had Office repaired.) I have set all trust settings in word and excel to the most lenient options.

I was able to launch Word and open a document using python's win32com library, so I think this is an issue isolated to the apps themselves, rather than the COM interface not being defined correctly.

So far, I've still been met with the same error 429 whenever I try running it in the Excel VBA editor.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I could what I need to do in another language, but I already have VBA code that does what I need from the old program, and other people will be using the spreadsheet, so it's convenient to just keep things contained within it, so that they can just press a button and it will run. Also want to know why this issue would arise in the first place.

Comment: Might be an over-cautious antivirus installation.